# Where should the sendView method of Google Analytics be placed?

Tags: java, android, view, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics in an application and a question have raised up.
Where should this method be placed:

```
tracker.sendView(viewName);
```

in `onCreate` or `onResume`?

If I place it in the `onCreate` then it will log the screen only ones when it's created, but won't fire again when I came back to this screen during my application flow. So from this I understand that if I want to follow the full flow of the user experience it should be placed in the `onResume` method, right?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).